# Asymptotic bound of a simple alternating binomial sum

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients, algebraic-complexity

I'm a rather inexperienced researcher, I've been stuck on a question for a while. I would like to find the largest $N = f(n)$ that satisfies the following inequality:

$$\sum_{j = 0} ^ n  p^{n - j} (-1)^j \binom{N}{j}
 + 
\sum_{j = n + 1} ^ N (-1)^j \binom{N}{j} > 0$$
for all sufficiently large integers $n$, where $p$ is a fixed prime, say $p = 3$. I suspect that $N$ will be some function close to $n$, such as $n + logn$ or $(1 + \epsilon)n$, but I don't know how to proceed with this problem and I have tried all naive methods.

Notably, if $N = n$ exactly then this is sum is $(p - 1)^n > 0$ exactly by the binomial theorem. Any solutions or tips are appreciated.

Comment: Can we just take $p=1/2$?

Comment: Apologies, I just edited. Assume p> 1 is a prime.

Answer (score 1):

For some $p$ and $n$, such largest $N$ does not have to exist.

Indeed, the left-hand side of your inequality equals
$$\begin{aligned}L_p(n,N)
&:=\sum_{j=0}^n p^{n-j}(-1)^j \binom Nj
+\sum_{j=n+1}^N (-1)^j \binom Nj \\ 
&=\sum_{j=0}^n p^{n-j}(-1)^j \binom Nj
+\sum_{j=0}^N (-1)^j \binom Nj-\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j \binom Nj \\ 
&=\sum_{j=0}^n p^{n-j}(-1)^j \binom Nj
+(1-1)^N-\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j \binom Nj \\ 
&=\sum_{j=0}^n p^{n-j}(-1)^j \binom Nj
-\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j \binom Nj \\ 
&=\sum_{j=0}^n (p^{n-j}-1)(-1)^j \binom Nj  . 
\end{aligned}\tag{1}\label{1}$$

So, if e.g. $p=2$ and $n=5$, then
$$L_p(n,N)=L_2(5,N)=\frac{1}{24} \left(N^4-18 N^3+131 N^2-474 N+744\right)>0$$
for all $N$.

More generally, it follows from \eqref{1} that $L_p(n,N)$ is a polynomial in $N$ of degree $n-1$, with the leading coefficient $(-1)^{n-1}\frac{p-1}{(n-1)!}$. So, the set of the values of $N$ for which $L_p(n,N)>0$ is unbounded for each odd $n$.

---

*Remark:* Using the identity $\binom Nj=\binom{N-1}j+\binom{N-1}{j-1}$, one gets the recursion
$$L_p(n,N)=L_p(n,N-1)-L_p(n-1,N-1),$$
with $L_p(0,N)=0$ and $L_p(n,0)=p^n-1$.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am actually looking for a N such that the left hand side is greater than 0 for all sufficiently large integers n. In fact, I am interested in the asymptotics where N is a fixed function and n tends toward infinity.

Comment: @JasonZheng : As I understood, you now want to have a function $f$ such that $L_p(n,N)\le0$ for **all large enough $n$** and all $N>f(n)$, right? It is shown in the answer that such a function $f$ does not exist. Indeed, if you take any, arbitrarily large odd $n$, then the set of the values of $N$ for which $L_p(n,N)>0$ will be unbounded. Let me know if this seems unclear.

Comment: @iosofPinelis Sorry, but how did you obtain the identity (1)? I am not understanding how the expression L_p(n,N) is equal to the left side of my inequality.

Comment: @JasonZheng It is because $\sum_{j=0}^N \binom Nj (-1)^j=0$. Binomial expansion for $(1-1)^N$.

Comment: @JasonZheng : Brendan McKay's comment explains how (1) was obtained. Is this detailed enough for you? Please let me know.

Comment: @JasonZheng : I have added these details anyway. Please let me know if anything still seems unclear. If everything is clear now, then [these guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers) may be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

*Since @Iosif Pinelis already gave the answer, this is too long for a comment.*

Formula $(1)$ could be obtained simplifying for $N>1$
$$\left(\frac{p-1}{p}\right)^N\, p^n-\frac {(-1)^n }{N p}\binom{N}{n+1}\Bigg((n+1)p -N \, _2F_1\left(1,n-N+1;n+2;\frac{1}{p}\right)\Bigg)$$ where

$$ \, _2F_1\left(1,n-N+1;n+2;\frac{1}{p}\right)=\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-N)! }\,\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(k+n-N)!}{(k+n+1)!}\, p^ {-n}$$

As far as I could see it, the problem is related to the parity of $n$.  For example

$$L_3(6,N)=-\frac{1}{60} \left(N^5-30 N^4+415 N^3-3450 N^2+17584 N-43680\right)$$ is positive if $N \leq 9$
$$L_3(7,N)=\frac{1}{360}\left(N^6-39 N^5+715 N^4-8205 N^3+63724 N^2-318276 N+786960\right)$$  is always positive.

Comment: To get (1), I was indeed reasoning as in [Brendan McKay's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463060/asymptotic-bound-of-a-simple-alternating-binomial-sum/463061#comment1202111_463061).

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis. I just wanted to see if I would be able to simplify my nasty expression and get your nice one.

Comment: I see; thank you for your response.